# Activity is shown after a strange delay

Tags: android, android-activity, delay

I'm suffering from a delay when starting an activity in my android application project.

Whenever a menu item or a clickable view is clicked, the onClickListener just creates a new Intent and starts specified activity. That's OK so far. But then, view is frozen for a noticeable time(around 1 sec) until user see the new activity.

That time may be caused by progress inside onCreate, but I measured time by System.currentTimeMillis() and printed it in logcat at the end. So it seems it takes only 20-30 ms and the log is printed long before user sees the activity.

Here is my code:

```
public class ExampleActivity extends MyActivity {

    MyModel myModel;
    long startTime;


    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_ders_programi);
        setToolbar();

        myModel = Controller.getMyModel();
        if(myModel == null) { //If we don't have the object previously
            //this fills the object, takes some time
            myModel = new MyModel(this);
            //myModel is observable and this activity is observer.
            //Whenever it's done, it notifies this activity
        }
        else //If we got the object previously
            createCardViews();
        Controller.setMyModel(myModel);

        setParentActivity();
    }


    //If Observable object notifies this activity, update() is called.
    @Override
    public void update(Observable observable, Object o) {
        createCardViews();
    }


   //Creating a list of cardViews, this also takes some time
   private void createCardViews() {
       ArrayList<Card> cards = new ArrayList<Card>();
       for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
           MyModelCardModel card = new MyModelCardModel(this, i);
           card.init();
           cards.add(card);
       }

       CardArrayAdapter mCardArrayAdapter = new CardArrayAdapter(this,cards);

       CardListView listView = (CardListView) findViewById(R.id.my_card_list_view);
       if (listView!=null)
           listView.setAdapter(mCardArrayAdapter);

       //I think here is the last point.
       //After this point there will be no significant process.
       long stopTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
       Log.d("modelflow", "card create takes: " + (stopTime - startTime) + "ms");

}
```

So what am I doing wrong? If the delay is because the progress is heavy, then why the measured time seems little. Let's say progress causes delay, why don't application wait after showing the activity? And how to avoid this?

Comment: How do you measure this time? is it a debug build? Do you measure your time in debug mode? What is OS version and device model?

Comment: @ViktorYakunin As you can see in the code above, I used 2 variables named _startTime_ and _stopTime_. At the end, I printed the difference between them to logcat. I didn't use debug mode. Applicaiton is running on my own phone, Samsung Galaxy S4, OS is Android 4.4.2. But same problem in emulator, Nexus S with Android 5.0

Comment: Try to move the intense-processing code inside another lifecycle method - perhaps `onResume()`, and see if the lag disappears.

Comment: @Safa Kadir it is not obvious from your question, and just in case, debug builds are not optimized and perform poorly if compare to release version.

Comment: @nightfixed Remembering I had tried it and lag didn't disappear. But it was before some changes. I'll try it again.

Comment: What does Controller.setMyModel() do. It gets called after you get the stopTime. Why did you put the stop time in a different place than the start time? Seems like an easy way to make the mistake you did and not get accurate timing.

Comment: @iheanyi setMyModel() just saves the instane to a static field to be reachable from other methods and classes via a getMyModel() call. Actually nothing more than a basic setter.

Answer (score 0):

There is a project to test native apps performance in comparison to polymer+xwalk. You can find sources here https://github.com/collabora/xw-perf
this project proves that native apps perform much better but the delay for start activity and GC is noticeable. Also it is interesting to see how GC causes fps drops.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is either with Controller.SetMyModel() or setParentActivity().

Why do I narrow it down to those?

1. You time everything but those two calls.
2. Everything timed seems to run quickly.
3. There is no source code for either of those un-timed calls.
4. Those calls don't appear to be to Android methods with known behavior.

Given your description of Controller.SetMyModel() as being

> Actually nothing more than a basic setter

the most likely candidate is setParentActivity(). You should post its source code.